# Mojolicious custom error pages with non-ERP renderer?

Tags: perl, mojolicious, custom-error-pages

According to the docs,

> You can also change the templates of those pages, since you most likely want to show your users something more closely related to your application in production. **The renderer will always try to find `exception.$mode.$format.*` or `not_found.$mode.$format.*`** before falling back to the built-in default templates.

Where is that logic? If implementing our own renderer, do we implement that as independent tries?

I don't see the `mode` called anywhere in the [`Mojolicious::Renderer` source](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Renderer.txt). How do we properly implement a renderer such that the above behavior from the docs works (the mode and fallback wo/ the mode).